# Python - os.system - how do I delete a temporary file?

Tags: python, system

I'm trying to delete a temporary file using Python. My OS is Windows.

Now, I noticed that it makes sense for me to use `os.system("del xxx")` to remove that file, but is there a way to make it universal? For example, to make it also work on Macs or Linux? I know that those systems use "rm" rather than "del".

Thanks!

Comment: How did you make the temporary file? `tempfile.TemporaryFile` self-deletes on close.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`os.remove`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove) instead of `os.system`:

```
os.remove('/path/to/temporary_file')
```

Comment: or you can use os.remove for individual files. It's a good habit to always use os or shutil instead of system specific commands just so you get cross-platform behavior for free

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html). This should be the preferred way when working with temporary files.